# data layout for faceting in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, formatting, facet

New to R: I have a large data set that I would like to visualize in facets. An example data frame:

```
Sample <- c("Hair", "Hair", "Hair", "Skin", "Skin", "Skin")
Drug <- c("Vehicle", "Drug1", "Drug2", "Vehicle", "Drug1", "Drug2")
Param1 <- c(2,4,6,2,3,6)
Param2 <- c(10,15,20,10,18,23)
data <- data.frame(Sample,Drug,Param1,Param2)
```

I can make a faceted image for `Param1` with:

```
ggplot (data, aes(x=Drug, y=Param1)) + geom_point() +facet_grid(.~Sample)
```

However I would like Param2 to be visualized in the same faceted output. So far I did this by reformatting the data frame as below, however this would be time-consuming for the larger data set that I have:

```
data2 <- data [,1:2]
data3 <- data2
data2 <- rbind (data2,data3)
Parameter <- c(rep(1,6),rep(2,6))
Combo = c(Param1,Param2)
data2 <- data.frame (data2, Combo, Parameter)
ggplot (data2, aes(x=Drug, y=Combo)) + geom_point() + facet_grid (Parameter~Sample)
```

Would it be possible to use the `data` data.frame to achieve the same faceted image that was shown in the plot of `data2`? Thanks very much for any help or advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are actually trying to do is reshaping your data and them plotting it. Now you have done this manually, but this can be done programmaticaly with the `dplyr` and `tidyr` packages:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data2 <- data %>% gather(Parameter, Combo, c(Param1,Param2))

ggplot(data2, aes(x=Drug, y=Combo, color=Parameter)) +
  geom_point(size=3) +
  facet_grid(Parameter~Sample) +
  theme(axis.title.y=element_blank())
```

this gives:
[image]

Instead of the combination of `dplyr` and `tidyr`, you can also use the `reshape2` package.

---

As an alternative you can consider the following solution:

```
ggplot (data, aes(x=Drug, y=Param1)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color="red"), size=3) +
  geom_point(aes(x=Drug, y=Param2, color="blue"), size=3) +
  scale_color_manual("Parameter", values=c("red","blue"), labels=c("Param1","Param2")) +
  facet_grid(.~Sample) +
  theme(axis.title.y=element_blank())
```

this gives:
[image]

Comment: Awesome!  Will try to learn the reshaping packages above.  Just to clarify: It is necessary to reshape the data because it is not possible to facet "across" columns.  One can only facet based on data within a single column.  Thanks for the nice solution.

Comment: @bio_r_learner That's right, facetting across columns is not possible. You need to reshape your data for that.